# Plotting data stored in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, plot, time-series

I've data written to dictionaries which has the following form:

```
observed [place_id][date][time] = value_observed

simulated [place_id][date][time] = value_simulated
```

there are total of 200 place_ids and dates cover 1 year (365 days) and each date (or day) covers 24 hours of data such as shown below for one site for a day:

```
observed ['11A346']['2009-08-07']{'19:00': 0.031125, '12:00': 0.028375, '06:00': 0.022249999999999995, '00:00': 0.03425, '23:00': 0.027749999999999997, '05:00': 0.023624999999999997, '11:00': 0.027125, '14:00': 0.031375, '04:00': 0.025124999999999998, '09:00': 0.022375000000000003, '03:00': 0.0265, '18:00': 0.0315, '01:00': 0.033125, '21:00': 0.029124999999999998, '15:00': 0.032625, '22:00': 0.028374999999999997, '08:00': 0.022, '16:00': 0.03275, '02:00': 0.031375, '13:00': 0.030000000000000002, '20:00': 0.03025, '07:00': 0.021749999999999995, '17:00': 0.032125, '10:00': 0.023125}
```

I wish to plot the timeseries of the "observed" and "simulated" data matching for every hour, and for selected subset of days. Right now I am writing the data to lists and dates to another list through a for loop and plotting through these lists. Is there any other way I can do it more easily, i.e. directly plotting from the dictionaries?

Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your plotting library is expecting, but rather than using a for loop to write the dates and values to lists, you should just call the keys() and values() methods which will both return the lists of keys and values respectively.  If your plotting library works like matplotlib and expects a list of x values and a list of y values, then you can just do something like:

```
d = observed['11A346']['2009-08-07']
plt.plot(d.keys(), d.values())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My plotting library is matplotlib.Yes, I can do like that, but the problem is large number of days and I don't want to  handle each separately. I have to plot yearlong timeseries, and if I can directly use values from dictionary, that will make it easier to plot and handle the data.